# Generate 32bit on 64bit machine

Tags: fortran, 32bit-64bit, cross-compiling, gfortran

I wish to generate 32 bit Fortran binaries on my 64 bit Win 7 Pro machine (using 64 bit gfortran in Cygwin) so I can then run them on my 32 bit Win 7 machine (using 32 bit Cygwin).
Is this doable with a switch at compile and/or link time?

Answer (score 2):

You can cross-compile your code, but you'll probably need a cross-toolchain (i.e. cross mingw/Cygwin). Then you can add `--target=` to specify e.g. `i686` or `i586`, depending on what the toolchain supports.

My guess is that it would be easiest to use a 32bit Cygwin installation instead and do a "native" build.